# Order of Operations: Denoise, Resize, Threshold

Tags: image-processing

I am writing a program for converting microscopy images to a FEA model using Python and scikit-image. As part of it, I am writing a function which opens the grayscale image and has to do the following:

1. Denoise the image using the denoise_bilateral() function.
2. Resize the image using the rescale() function.
3. Apply a threshold using Otsu's Method.

I understand that users may need a more sophisticated algorithm, and encourage it in the docs, but this function will be an easy starting point.

My question is: Does the order of the above operations matter? In which order should they be performed?

Comment: The answer is "yes it does" -- why don't you experiment with it, though, and let us know what happens?  Make yourself a really high-resolution image of a boring scene, and add lots of noise to it.  Then try running the above operations in forward, and in reverse, and in the other 4 possible orders.  See how it looks.

Comment: (Note -- many denoising algorithms are linear and shift-invariant, involving convolution.  Rescaling can be linear, but _not_ shift invariant, because you're throwing away pixels.  Applying a threshold is about as nonlinear as you can get.  And changing the order of operations when some of the operations are nonlinear or shift-varying will change the results).

Comment: @TimWescott I was hoping to find a suitable order for a generic algorithm and recommend a more sophisticated algorithm for real-world data. I don't think any experimentation on my part will provide useful data and will probably settle for the current rescale-denoise-threshold order. That said, thank you and please submit this as an answer.